# Спецификация исключений C++

Tags: c++, исключения

Как сейчас правильно указывать, что функция выбрасывает исключения? Писать `throw(...)` или перечислять возможные исключения или вообще ничего не писать?

И еще вопрос: что указывается в скобках после `noexcept`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Если функция *выбрасывает* исключения - то ничего не писать. (Или можно эквивалентно написать `noexcept(false)`).

Что указывается в скобках `noexcept` зависит от того, о каком `noexcept` вы говорите. Есть *оператор* `noexcept`, а есть *спецификатор* `noexcept`.

- Оператор `noexcept` *проверяет* noexcept-статус выражения. Это оператор времени компиляции. В качестве операнда указывается выражение, чей noexcept-статус вы хотите узнать. Оператор на стадии компиляции вернет `true` или `false`.
- Спецификатор `noexcept` наоборот *назначает* noexcept-статус функции. Он декларирует, является ли данная функция `noexcept` или не является. Просто `noexcept` говорит, что функция является `noexcept`. А в варианте с булевским операндом noexcept-статус определяется значением булевского выражения.

Например, в следующем примере используется как оператор `noexcept`, так и спецификатор `noexcept`

```
void bar() noexcept(noexcept(foo()));
           ^        ^
           |        |
           |        оператор
           спецификатор
```

Функция `bar()` в результате получит тот же noexcept-статус, что и функция `foo()`.

Comment: А как же тогда быть со спецификацией исключений через throw. Почему она [отмечена устаревшей](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec)? На мой взгляд удобный механизм (в целях самодокументирования). Работал бы ещё на этапе компиляции (а-ля как в java) — цены б ему не было…

Comment: @mymedia: "Официальные" причины отмены: проверка в run-time, в случае нарушения невозможно восстановление, большие накладные расходы, неприменимость в generic коде, где  спецификация исключений вызываемого кода не может быть предсказана вообще (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3051.html). Более детально тему разбирает Herb Sutter в http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm. Это обширная тема, в комменатриях подробно не распишешь.